# Efficient method to print the content of an Ienumerable

Tags: .net, vb.net, join, for-loop, ienumerable

I have this "result" var which is a `IEnumerable` type:

```
Dim result = GetCombinations(TextBox1.Text, StringLength)
```

To get/write the content of the variable I need to iterate all the items inside using a For and then convert each item to an array, like this:

```
    For Each item In result
        RichTextBox1.Text += vbNewLine & item.ToArray
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next
```

...So my answer is If I can improve my code for example to join the IEnumerable content to do something like this else:

```
 RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, result) ' This does not work.
```

I mean, a "in one go" thing.

If not, any alternative better (faster) than the For?

> UPDATE

This is the full code:

```
Private Shared Function GetCombinations(Of T)(list As IEnumerable(Of T), length As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))

    If length = 1 Then
        Return list.[Select](Function(x) New T() {x})
    Else
        Return GetCombinations(list, length - 1).SelectMany(Function(x) list, Function(t1, t2) t1.Concat(New T() {t2}))
    End If

End Function

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    RichTextBox1.Clear()

    Dim result = GetCombinations("abc", 5)

    ' Dim result2 As IEnumerable(Of String) = result.Select(Function(item) New String(item))

    ' RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, result)

    For Each item In result
        RichTextBox1.Text &= vbNewLine & item.ToArray
        '  Application.DoEvents()
    Next

End Sub
```

> UPDATE 2

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Method result
    Dim result As IEnumerable = Permute_Characters("abc", 2)

    ' Combine strings into lines
    ' Dont work
    RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.ToString.ToArray)

End Sub
```

Comment: To make it faster, remove the `DoEvents`. Also, why the inconsistency? You are using `+=` for string concatenation but also `&`.

Comment: Why Application.DoEvents() in the loop?

Comment: If each item in result is a `Char` then what does the `item.ToArray()` do? Did you mean `IEnumerable(Of Char())`?

Comment: @ja72 yes I would mean **IEnumerable(Of Char())** sorry for this newbie confussion.

Comment: @Blam to don't "hang" the application when printing the content on the RichTextbox control

Comment: If it hangs without the Application.DoEvents() then you do have a problem.  Try the answer from Tombala.

Comment: Is `T` ever anything but `Char`?

Comment: Can you give and example of you are trying to achieve. I think your problem is not how to handle `result` but the function `GetCombinations()` itself.

Comment: @ja72 the function is really perfect, the fastest, the most efficient, and does what I need, my problem is I want to load all the permutations without iterating the IEnumarable rows, I mean without using a For to iterate the items, so I want to load it in "one go" for example using a "string.join" (like in the Sub Main() of your newest updated answer).

Comment: Is this happen to be for [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problems) or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want speed and reduced memory footprint, then reduce the recursions and calls to LINQ (which hide internal loops).

Now that I understand what you want, try this code

```
Public Function GetCombinations(ByVal letters As String, ByVal word_length As Integer) As String()
    ' abc,2 -> aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc
    ' abc,3 -> aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, .. , caa, cab, cac
    Dim list = letters.ToCharArray()
    Dim N_letters = list.Length
    Dim N_combinations = CLng(Math.Pow(N_letters, word_length))
    Dim result As New List(Of String)(N_combinations)
    ' indeces holds which letter to use for each combination
    ' 0 = a, 1 = b, 2 = c, ...
    ' it starts with (0,0,0..) which corresponds to "aaa.."
    Dim indeces As Integer() = New Integer(word_length-1) {}
    'Default to 0's
    Dim k As Integer
    Do
        ' convert indeces into combination, example: (1,0,2) => (b,a,c) => "bac"
        result.Add(New String(indeces.Select(Function(x) list(x)).ToArray()))
        'Find next combination by incrementing the first letter,
        'and if it spills-over, reset it to 'a' and try the next letter in the word
        k = 0
        Do
            indeces(k) += 1

            If indeces(k) = N_letters Then
                indeces(k) = 0
                k = k + 1
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop While k < word_length
    Loop While k < word_length

    Return result.ToArray()

End Function


Sub Main()
    Dim result = GetCombinations("abc", 5)
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(ControlChars.CrLf, result))
End Sub
```

with results

```
aaaaa
baaaa
caaaa
abaaa
bbaaa
cbaaa
acaaa
bcaaa
ccaaa
aabaa
babaa
...
caccc
abccc
bbccc
cbccc
acccc
bcccc
ccccc
```

Comment: It throws an aritmetic error operation with bigger numbers : Dim result = GetCombinations("abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz", 8) but I accept the answer 'cause you are great and I can learn things in this code, but I prefer to use the For, see my last comment on @Tombala solution if want to know why. Thanks for all.

Comment: There is a memory limit on arrays, and with these large numbers you hit it hard. In general a `.NET` object must be less than 2Gb in size. The 26^8=208827064576 combinations each with 4bytes means 780Gb of data. Good luck with those kind of numbers!

Answer (score 2):

Every time you update RichTextBox.Text property, you're probably going to incur an overhead as it does its own internal logic. Also, you're reading the value first so double that overhead right there.

Instead, I would use a StringBuilder in the loop. You can use the Append method overload of StringBuilder to add your characters to it. [This overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h6b6ew9.aspx) accepts a character array.

Finally once your StringBuilder is built, then you can call RichTextBox1.Text = mystringbuilder.ToString().

This way you would avoid calling the "Clear" method of rich textbox as well as reading and reassigning the text property of it for every line. You will also avoid creating excessive amounts of string copies in memory that get generated when you do string concatenation operations.

EDIT PER COMMENTS:
To do this in a single line without looping, you could use the LINQ extension function [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I use C# but you can use the VB syntax for this.

```
var v = GetCombinations(...);
RichTextBox1.Text = v.Aggregate((str, p) => str + Environment.NewLine + p);
```

But this still does string concatenations so I still suggest using a StringBuilder.

Comment: First thankyou for your suggestions, but even using stringbuilder or not, the question is how I can "load" the IEnumerable content in "one go" instead of using a For (with or without a stringbuilder) for example using String.Join, see my updated question please, thanks

Comment: You can use the Aggregate function to do it without a loop. Edited my answer.

Comment: now it seems to be the simplest and best solution all in one line, but is very difficult for me to translate the "p =>" part to vbnet, also the online translators throws an error, can you please translate the last line?

Comment: I got the translation, no matter, **v.Aggregate(Function(str, p) str.ToArray & Environment.NewLine & p.ToArray)**, but now I can notice this was not a good idea, the best is using a For because when trying to add the full result in a stringbuilder using this solution or the @ja72 solution it takes months to load the data in memory and hangs the PC forever, the problem is when converting to chararray like in your update or ja72 update, so after all the better is to iterate it using a For for big number of permutations, thanks.

Comment: Do post your latest code please. Fully functioning code would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer to updated question:

This code works as intended (the best I can surmise)

```
Private Function GetCombinations(ByVal list As Char(), ByVal length As Integer) As Char()()
    If length = 1 Then
        Return list.[Select](Function(x) (New Char() {x})).ToArray()
    Else
        Return GetCombinations(list, length - 1).SelectMany(Function(x) list, Function(t1, t2) t1.Concat(New Char() {t2}).ToArray()).ToArray()
    End If
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim result = GetCombinations("abc".ToCharArray(), 3)
    Dim list = result.Select(Function(x) New String(x)).ToArray()
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list))
End Sub
```

With results:

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca
acb
acc
baa
bab
bac
bba
bbb
bbc
bca
bcb
bcc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

It may not be the most efficient, but it is a start as the OP code did not work. It hinges on converting a jagged array of characters into an array of strings. Each row is converted from an array of char into a string using `New String(x)`.

Comment: Does not work on my side, but I think is my fault, this is the type of my IEnumerable: **<SelectManyIterator>d__31(Of IEnumerable(Of Char),Char,IEnumerable(Of Char))** when I try to use your "Dim result2" it throws an exception with my original "result" var : **Conversion from type '<ConcatIterator>d__71(Of Char)' to type 'Char()' is not valid.**

Comment: @ElektroHacker, please update your question with the correct information. You are making it impossible to answer as it is.

Comment: OK I will put the entire code as is, give me a sec, thankyou for your comprenssion, UPDATED!

Comment: Your code has an error in `GetCombinations()`. Try changing to `Return list.[Select](Function(x) (New Char() {x}).AsEnumerable())`

Comment: I appreciate your time but sorry I can't accept your answer, the modifications you've made in the function takes big consecuencies, the original function "loads" a permutation of 26 characters and 9 length of string in less than one second, your modification hangs the PC and the consumition of memory take big values. The "Sub Main()" is doing what I need, it is a pity.