# How to find possible set of k Elements from array?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I have an array `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and I have to find all combinations of k elements from `array` and k will be dynamic. So for 4 elements below code is sufficient but i have to make this dynamic means,it is not fixed that how many `for` loops will be used, so please suggest some solution for this.

```
 for (i = 0; i < len - 3; i++)    
 {   
    for (j = i + 1; j < len - 2; j++)           
    {
       for (y = j + 1; y < len - 1; y++)              
       {                
          for (k = y + 1; k < len; k++)                    
          Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3}", s[i], s[j],s[y], s[k]);             
       }                
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know if you read the blog I mentioned the last time you posted this question, but it literally has the code that will do this for you.  http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/

Comment: i don't want to use linq.

Comment: Do you want to find all combinations?

Comment: yes i want to find to find all combinations of k elements.

Comment: That post doesn't "use Linq".  It does use extension methods, but if you prefer not to you can still learn from that code.

Comment: i have to use basic c# only

Comment: Then you need to define exactly what you mean by "basic c#".  Are you limited to .net 2.0?  Except for the extension method at the end, which can just be used as a regular static method if you so choose, I'm pretty sure everything else could be compiled in 2.0.

Comment: Basically i have to change these loops to recursive function and i am not so much good in recursive functions so anyone who is expert in recursion please help me

Comment: Do you have anything which determines your set or number of elements that will be used or extracted when the functions starts

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16988082/380384) help?

Comment: Does order matters or you just want combinations? Is `{1,2}` equals `{2,1}` when combinations of size 2 is needed?

Comment: It seems like a homework about recursion, that's sad that you have to ask for solving your hw here

Comment: why do u think it is a homework,i am asking solution for my problem

Comment: It's because only homework asks for an abstract solution like this using "only basic C#". If it was for work, you could use whatever you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to replace `i, j, y, ...` with array and manually unroll the `for` loops like this

```
static void PrintCombinations(int[] input, int k)
{
    var indices = new int[k];
    for (int pos = 0, index = 0; ; index++)
    {
        if (index <= input.Length - k + pos)
        {
            indices[pos++] = index;
            if (pos < k) continue;
            // Consume the combination
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0) Console.Write(",");
                Console.Write(input[indices[i]]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            pos--;
        }
        else
        {
            if (pos == 0) break;
            index = indices[--pos];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this methods for generating combinations of size l

```
public static List<List<T>> GenerateCombinations<T>(List<T> items, int l)
{
    if (l == 0)
        return new List<List<T>> { new List<T>() };

    var allCombs = new List<List<T>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
    {
        var listWithRemovedElement = new List<T>(items);
        listWithRemovedElement.RemoveRange(0, i + 1);

        foreach (var combination in GenerateCombinations(listWithRemovedElement, l - 1))
        {
            var comb = new List<T>(listWithRemovedElement.Count + 1);
            comb.Add(items[i]);
            comb.AddRange(combination);
            allCombs.Add(comb);
        }
    }
    return allCombs;
}
```

You can use this methods for generating permutations of size l

```
public static List<List<T>> GeneratePermutations<T>(List<T> items, int l)
{
    if (l == 0)
        return new List<List<T>> { new List<T>() };

    var allCombs = new List<List<T>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
    {
        var listWithRemovedElement = new List<T>(items);
        listWithRemovedElement.RemoveAt(i);

        foreach (var combination in GeneratePermutations(listWithRemovedElement, l - 1))
        {
            var comb = new List<T>(listWithRemovedElement.Count + 1);
            comb.Add(items[i]);
            comb.AddRange(combination);
            allCombs.Add(comb);
        }
    }
    return allCombs;
}
```

Permutationsof `{ 1, 2, 3 }` with size of 2

```
var result = GeneratePermutations(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }, 2);
foreach (var perm in result)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", perm));

1,2
1,3
2,1
2,3
3,1
3,2
```

Combinations of `{ 1, 2, 3 }` with size of 2

```
var result = GenerateCombinations(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }, 2);
foreach (var comb in result)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", comb));

1,2
1,3
2,3
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how I'd do it in "real life", but since this seems to be a simple homework-style problem aimed at getting you to use recursion and with the aim of simply writing out the combinations, this is a reasonably simple solution:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] test = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int k = 4;

        WriteCombinations(test, k);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void WriteCombinations(int[] array, int k, int startPos = 0, string prefix = "")
    {
        for (int i = startPos; i < array.Length - k + 1; i++)
        {
            if (k == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", prefix, array[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                string newPrefix = array[i].ToString();
                if (prefix != "")
                {
                    newPrefix = string.Format("{0}, {1}", prefix, newPrefix);
                }
                WriteCombinations(array, k - 1, i + 1, newPrefix);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If having optional parameters is not "basic" enough, then you can either take away the default values and pass in `0` and `""` on the first call, or you can create another "wrapper" method that takes fewer parameters and then calls the first method with the defaults.