# Permutations in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that outputs all possible permutations starting with a column of some numbers where each consecutive number can't be greater than the number above it.

So, would I would like to do is to provide excel with a column of 15 values in `Sheet1` ranging from `1` to `9`. The values should be in descending order so that a number on a row below can never exceed the one above.

What I am trying to do is to output new permutations of this list, one  new sheet per new list.

The upper limit of the values in the list would be specified so the number of permutations would be everything between the starting list and the upper limit value.

There is a condition that I can not break and that is that the value of a row below another row, can't have a greater value than the one above. There's an image that explains a bit.

So far my code is not even half way there and I feel completely lost.
I'm not even sure how to go about thinking about this problem let alone coding it.
Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub

    doSomeStuff()

    Dim maxNotch, startNotch, Counter As Integer
    Dim shit As Range

    maxNotch = 3
    startNotch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)


    Counter = startNotch
    sheetnumber = 2
    For j = st

    artNotch To maxNotch

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Sheet" & sheetnumber

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & sheetnumber).Cells(2, 2).Value = Counter
    For i = 1 To 3

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & sheetnumber).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 2 + i

        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & sheetnumber).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> Counter Then
           k = Counter - ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & sheetnumber - 1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
           Debug.Print k
        End If

    Next i


    sheetnumber = sheetnumber + 1
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Next j

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Function pop()

    (ByVal j As Integer, k As Integer)
    For i = 1 To 3

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & j + 1).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 2 + i
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & j + 1).Cells(2, 2).Value = Counter


        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & j + 1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> Cou

    nter Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & j + 1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & j).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, if you have 1, 2 and 3, are you expecting these combinations ... 111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 131, 132, 133, 211, 212, 213, 221, 222, 223, 231, etc. So every permutation of the characters you have at hand?

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16988082/380384) maybe (code must be ported from VB.NET to VBA) to get all the different permutations.

Comment: Why not use `.Sort` for your range with descending order?  Sink that into a loop for your sheets `For each ws in Worksheets` and you're solid (dynamically determine last row in each ws to help define your range).

Answer (score 0):

Example from my comment, to account for the ordering:

```
dim pc as long, ws as worksheet
for each ws in worksheets
    with ws
        If ws.name <> "sourcedatasheet" then
            .cells(2,2).resize(pc).value = "" 'export your list; pc = permutation count
            .Range(.Cells(1,2),.Cells(pc+1,2)).Sort key1:=.Cells(1,2), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes 'used a header because row 1 is blank
        end if
    end with
next
```

---

**Edit1:**

Adding an if-statement to account for some specific sheet to not be included